# Matlab shrink image array based on another array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array that is holding an image of size (560 x 296) which is the original image that I input into my program. Now I have another array of the same size (560 x 296) that is filled with 0s and 1s. The 1s mark the position of pixels I want to keep in the original image, and the 0s mark the pixels I want to remove from the original image.

Is there some sort of fancy matlab function that shrinks an array based on another array?

Any help/links would be awesome as I am new to Matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `B` is a logical array, you want either

```
A(~B) = 0;
```

or

```
A(~B) = [];
```

Only the first is guaranteed to preserve the shape of A, but it doesn't really remove them: it only blanks them.